# How to disable "Use Strict" in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, use-strict

I am writing some unit tests for a codebase which uses octal literals. Whenever the test is executed with `npm test`, a syntax error appears as follows:

> Legacy octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.

I should stress that `"use strict"` does not appear anywhere in the source code, nor can I identify any option in `package-lock.json` or `package.json` indicating strict mode. Both JSON files were created with the `npm init -y` and received no further modification except the addition of:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
```

How can I force Jest out of strict mode in order to test code with legacy octal literals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transform-objectstring-pathtotransformer--pathtotransformer-object):

> By default, Jest will use `babel-jest` transformer

You can explicitly tell Jest you don't want it to try to apply any transforms by setting the following Jest configuration (e.g. in `jest.config.<ext>` or under `$.jest` in the package file):

```json
"transform": {}
```

See full example below. Alternatively, you can leave Babel's transforms active but [configure](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#configuration-file-types) it with [`"sourceType": "script"`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#sourcetype).

---

- `package.json`:

  ```json
  {
    "name": "strict-jest",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "jest"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
      "jest": "^28.1.2"
    },
    "jest": {
      "transform": {}
    }
  }
  ```
- `index.test.js`:

  ```js
  it("works", () => {
    expect(0100).toEqual(64);
  });
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  $ npm t

  > strict-jest@0.1.0 test
  > jest

   PASS  ./index.test.js
    ✓ works (2 ms)

  Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
  Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
  Snapshots:   0 total
  Time:        0.257 s
  Ran all test suites.
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue while working with Jest and TypeScript.

What worked for me was to set `"strict": false` and `"noImplicitUseStrict": true` in my `tsconfig.json` file. I also removed any jest transformations in my `jest.config.ts` file, like so: `"transform": {}`